# Defining xor in Scheme

Tags: scheme

How can I define the function xor, where the number of arguments could be anywhere from 0 to n.

```
(xor true true true true) -> false
(xor true false false false true) -> true
```

etc....

Comment: You are going to have to show some effort. Edit: Also, they are called procedures in Scheme ;p

Comment: Hint: write a binary version of xor (one that takes two args). Now think about how you can use reduce with that binary xor to make a variable arity xor.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a skeletal solution:

```
(define (xor . vals)
  (define (inner vals)
    (cond ((null? vals) <???>)
          ((null? (cdr vals)) <???>)   ;; optional optimisation
          ((car vals) (not <???>))
          (else <???>)))
  (inner vals))
```

Figure out what all the `<???>` are.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the top result for `scheme xor` but the votes show the answer value